# How to turn StandardScaller back to dummy 1, 0?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a following problem. For the purpose of my neural network, I reshape input data using `StandardScaler()`. See:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

predictors_scaler = StandardScaler()
target_scaler = StandardScaler()

predictor_scaler_fit = predictors_scaler.fit(X_train)
target_scaler_fit = target_scaler.fit(np.array(y_train).reshape(-1, 1))
predictor_scaler_fit_test = predictors_scaler.fit(X_test)

X_train1 = predictor_scaler_fit.transform(X_train)
X_test1 = predictor_scaler_fit_test.transform(X_test)

y_train1 = target_scaler_fit.transform(np.array(y_train).reshape(-1, 1))
```

Predicted values looks like this now:

```py
print(y_train) #original data
       recommends_us
2416                1
7218                1
11907               1
3914                1
16200               0
               ...
13123               1
19648               1
9845                1
10799               1
2732                0

############################
print(y_train1) #after transformation
[[ 0.3659399 ]
 [ 0.3659399 ]
 [ 0.3659399 ]
 ...
 [ 0.3659399 ]
 [ 0.3659399 ]
 [-2.73268916]]
```

Now I predict new y_values using:

```py
model = make_model(X_train1, y_train1, X.shape[1], epoch = 10)

prediction = model.predict(X_test1)
y_prediction_inverse = target_scaler.inverse_transform(prediction) # I TRY TO CONVERT IT BACK!!!!
```

But transformed `y_prediction_inverse` looks like this:

```py
print(y_prediction_inverse)
[[0.7743259 ]
 [0.95401525]
 [0.7513208 ]
 ...
 [0.8158173 ]
 [0.8363164 ]
 [0.9120644 ]]
```

Of course, I need `y_prediction_inverse` to be 1 or 0. How can I do this, please?

Comment: Mine is just a guess but, perhaps you should give some more hints on your data or model; actually running it on a toy dataset with a logistic regression works. One question only, why are you fitting your `predictor_scaler` on `X_test`, too?

Comment: Moreover, consider that sklearn also has [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) which actually does what you're trying to achieve under the hood, while performing the estimation. Perhaps it might be useful.